# How can i calculate the proportion of data of two different groups in each bin in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have 2 groups of people, each of size n and with different values of an attribute, age for example.
I already graphed histograms of the two groups and saw how the data is distributed, given k bins (of the same size). However, now i want to calculate the proportion of people of group 1 that is in the bin 1, and the same for group 2, so i can calculate the difference of proportions.

Just to be clear, i don't want to calculate the frecuency of the bins, i already did that with "weights".

My data structure is: two matrices with attributes (one for each group). Each row is a different attribute (age for ex) and each column a person.

Answer (score 1):

The pricise way in which what you want can be accomplished depends on the data stracture you are using.

With `DataFrames.jl` you can proceed as follows. With your data in `df`

```
julia> df
120×3 DataFrame
│ Row │ age   │ groups │ bins             │
│     │ Int64 │ String │ Categorical…     │
├─────┼───────┼────────┼──────────────────┤
│ 1   │ 7     │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 2   │ 2     │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 3   │ 8     │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 4   │ 4     │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 5   │ 9     │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 6   │ 12    │ Group1 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 7   │ 5     │ Group2 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 8   │ 1     │ Group2 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 9   │ 16    │ Group2 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 10  │ 13    │ Group2 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
│ 11  │ 1     │ Group2 │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │
⋮
│ 109 │ 75    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 110 │ 82    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 111 │ 80    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 112 │ 80    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 113 │ 86    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 114 │ 77    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 115 │ 88    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 116 │ 75    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 117 │ 87    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 118 │ 79    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 119 │ 83    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
│ 120 │ 74    │ Group2 │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │
```

1. We first calculate the the number of observation in each group/bin cell

```
df2 = combine(groupby(df, [:groups, :bins]), :age => length => :num)
```

The column `:num` has the number of *obs* in each cell.

2. We calculate the number of observation in each group and then join the data frame with this info to `df2`. We calculate the proportion and sort by bin/group

```
df3 = combine(groupby(df, :groups), :age => length => :den)
df4 = join(df3, df2, on = :groups)
df4[:proportion] = df4.num./df4.den
sort!(df4, [:bins, :groups])
```

```
julia> df4
10×5 DataFrame
│ Row │ groups │ den   │ bins             │ num   │ proportion │
│     │ String │ Int64 │ Categorical…     │ Int64 │ Float64    │
├─────┼────────┼───────┼──────────────────┼───────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ Group1 │ 43    │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │ 6     │ 0.139535   │
│ 2   │ Group2 │ 77    │ Q1: [0.0, 16.8)  │ 18    │ 0.233766   │
│ 3   │ Group1 │ 43    │ Q2: [16.8, 36.6) │ 10    │ 0.232558   │
│ 4   │ Group2 │ 77    │ Q2: [16.8, 36.6) │ 14    │ 0.181818   │
│ 5   │ Group1 │ 43    │ Q3: [36.6, 52.4) │ 8     │ 0.186047   │
│ 6   │ Group2 │ 77    │ Q3: [36.6, 52.4) │ 16    │ 0.207792   │
│ 7   │ Group1 │ 43    │ Q4: [52.4, 71.4) │ 11    │ 0.255814   │
│ 8   │ Group2 │ 77    │ Q4: [52.4, 71.4) │ 13    │ 0.168831   │
│ 9   │ Group1 │ 43    │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │ 8     │ 0.186047   │
│ 10  │ Group2 │ 77    │ Q5: [71.4, 89.0] │ 16    │ 0.207792   │
```

Comment: or just `combine(groupby(df, [:groups, :bins]), :age => (x -> length(x)/nrow(df)) => :proportion)`

Comment: My data structure it's different but i guess i could change it to a data frame. How did you create the "bin categorical" column?

Comment: You can use `cut(df[:age], 6)` where 6 is the number of equally spaced interval.`cut` is in `CathegoricalArrays` and it allows different kind of bins (see the help)

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński I think what you propose does not give the proportions the poster is looking for. For these, the divisor is the number of observations in the group and not the number of observations in the whole DataFrame (`nrow(df)`).

Comment: Ah - you are right - I missed the question. If the proportion should be per group then `combine(groupby(df, [:groups, :bins]), nrow)` and then then group by `:groups` and then just use `x -> x ./ sum(x)` as a second transformation.

Comment: one last question! How can i calculate the difference of proportions of each group in each bin? For example, in bin 1, calculate 0,13 - 0,23.